# Simple python code is not responding

Tags: python, python-2.7

using python2.7 command line:

```
>>>ff = open("soso.txt","r")
>>>for line in ff:
... print line
...
```

it just freezes 
I tried to use read() it works, but why this ends here nothing is printed???
although I used the same code in pycharm and worked

Comment: It didn't freeze; the interpreter is simply waiting for a blank line to indicate you have finished with the body of the `for` loop before executing it.

Comment: what should I do ?

Comment: Give it a blank line by hitting enter.

Comment: Lol thanks alot it worked